# Phonegap/Cordova on Remote Server doesnt load on compiled APK

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

i've a problem using Phonegap on a remoteserver.

Since my app requires internet and the app should be loaded from the remote server i'm using content src="remote.server/index.php" which works fine.

When i start building an apk, it doesnt seems to load handlebars and other plugins.

Now i've tried debugging using ripple and figured out that the cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js are not generated, since they should be hosted on the server side.

Now i've made a switch using cordova.js and checking the user agent.

As soon as it matches android it includes the cordova.js included with the android build. Of course i do the same with ios and browser aswell.

After i've done that and trying again it still doesnt load everything successfull.

Chrome Webdeveloper gave me tons of errors like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

or
    Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Ive uploaded the plugins folder and the *.json files like android.json, browser.json, etc but it still doesnt load successfully.

Ive used this site for testing purpose

```
https://api.seiboldsoft.de/milchbar2000/native/index.php
```

and the configuration in the app

```
<access origin="*" />
<content src="https://api.seiboldsoft.de/milchbar2000/native/index.php" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="blob:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

What may be wrong? Did i miss something? I want to avoid hosting the site on the device, which means that it would be great to have it on the server side.

Comment: Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers? In addition, it is best practice to load the page from the device - not the Internet. If you load from the Internet, you will have performance problems.

Comment: have you solved your issue.